# Why prepend behaves differently on a Seq depending on how you call it?

Tags: scala

If I use the infix notation, I can append to an immutable `Seq` no trouble:

```
scala> Seq("b", "c") :+ "d"
res2: Seq[String] = List(b, c, d)
```

But if I'm trying a prepend, it considers the `String` instance as a `Seq` itself and result is different:

```
scala> Seq("b", "c") +: "a"
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Any] = Vector(List(b, c), a)
```

However, calling the method in a classic way does what is "expected":

```
scala> Seq("b", "c").+:("a")
res4: Seq[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

Why is it behaving this way and what method should be privileged to prepend a `String` element to a `Seq[String]` (idiomatic scala)?

> Environment: `Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every method ending with a colon (`:`) is right associative when used in the infix notation.

So you need to do `"a" +: Seq("b", "c")`.

`Seq("b", "c") +: "a"` worked because `String` is a `IndexedSeq[Char]` and you are prepending a `Seq` (with `List` as default implementation via `Seq.apply`) to this `String`, so you get `IndexedSeq[Any]`.

Answer (score 1):

You miss something on how the operator notation is transformed into a method call.

Most of the time `a op b` becomes `a.op(b)`

**BUT**, if the operator's name ends with a colon ':', then `a op b` is in fact `b.op(a)`.

So to call `seq.+:("a")`, you must write `"a" +: seq`. This is nicer, as "a" comes at the front of the result. And this is why the name is chosen to be `+:` (and the name of append is `+:`, just for symmetry).

On the other ends, when you write seq +: "a", it means "a".+:(seq) which should prepend `seq`, *as a single value*, (this is not `++`), to the String `"a"`, which is a `Seq[Char]`. As that single value is not a Char, the result cannot be a string, and it degenerates to a `List[Any]`, with mixed types.